# how to extract specific character from a string using regex

Tags: javascript, node.js, regex

I will have the following inputs from which i plan to extract the units
(expected output eg.: `g`, `l`, `kg`, `ml`, `l`) and the quantity if present (`20` in last input)

1. `0,5g`
2. `500l`
3. `1000kg`
4. `20,5ml`
5. `20x0,50l (1 l = 1,70 €) zzgl. 3,10€ Pfand`

if it's simple case i am doing the following

Input: `500g`

```
console.log("500g".replace(/ *\([^)]*\) */g, "") // remove brackets
      .replace(/[0-9]/g, "") // remove number eg. 500
      .replace(/\s/g, ""))
```

output: `g` ( works )

Input: `0,5g`

```
console.log("0,5g".replace(/ *\([^)]*\) */g, "") // remove brackets
  .replace(/[0-9]/g, "") // remove number eg. 500g
  .replace(/\s/g, ""))
```

output: `,g` ( breaks )

Input: `20x0,50l (1 l = 1,70 €) zzgl. 3,10€ Pfand`

```
  console.log("20x0,50l (1 l = 1,70 €) zzgl. 3,10€ Pfand".replace(/ *\([^)]*\) */g, "") // remove brackets
      .replace(/[0-9]/g, "") // remove number eg. 500g
      .replace(/\s/g, ""))
```

output: `x,lzzgl.,€Pfand` ( breaks )

Comment: Did any of the posted answers work out?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Instead of using `replace`, you might want to use `match`, which will return a match object.

[Mozilla Article](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/match)

---

Regex Patterns:

For matching values and units:

```
([\d,\.]+)\s*(g|kg|l|ml)
```

More units can be added in the last group.

Example:

```
"20x0,50l (1 l = 1,70 €) zzgl. 3,10€ Pfand".match(/([\d,\.]+)\s*(g|kg|l|ml)/)

returns
(3) ...:
    0: "0,50l" // full match
    1: "0,50" // value
    2: "l" // unit
    ...
```

For matching just units (though this is kind of unnecessary, the previous regex matches values in group 1, units in group 2 at the same time):

```
(?<=[\d,\.]+)\s*(g|kg|l|ml)
```

For matching quantities:

```
([\d,\.]+)(?:x|\*)
```

Example:

```
"20x0,50l (1 l = 1,70 €) zzgl. 3,10€ Pfand".match(/([\d,\.]+)(?:x|\*)/)

returns
(2) ...:
    0: "20x" // full match
    1: "20" // quantity
    ...
```

---

EDIT: to further elaborate on my comment

```
var units = ["g", "kg", "l", "ml"];
var re = new RegExp(`([\\d,\\.]+)\\s*(${units.join("|")})`);
```

Then using re for matching:

```
"20x0,50l (1 l = 1,70 €) zzgl. 3,10€ Pfand".match(re)
```

Works the same, but is more maintainable.

---

Comment: Super thanks for a new solution. I want to avoid doing something like this `g|kg|l|ml` since I am not aware of the units which will come as input beforehand

Comment: Well, you could just define all the units in an array and define the regex dynamically, inserting ```|``` between every unit, or in that case element in the array, converting it to a string. Regex is, in general, something hard to maintain. If you can avoid using Regex, you should; it's more of a last resort, or should be, anyway.

Comment: @SaurabhKumar you need to group the units somehow so if that is not mantainable use an array of units e.g. ["l", "kg"...]

Comment: @TARN4T1ON I think there is an unnecessary slash before point -> `\.` in `/([\d,\.]+)(?:x|\*)/) ` . Probably you can correct me if i am wrong. Thx in advance.

Comment: @SaurabhKumar You're right, but it doesn't affect the functionality in any way. To each their own, but I always go the safe route; ```\.``` is guaranteed to not be a wildcard. I won't say anything about improving readability, though; we're talking about regex, after all.

Comment: If I'm not mistaken, the goal is to do this without having a full list of units anywhere available, by assuming that in the correct input formats, the units can be extracted as the consecutive letters after a formatted number (possibly preceded by another number and `x`.)  That requires a somewhat different technique.

Answer (score 0):

You could use 2 capturing groups to extract the units and optional 20

```
(?:(\d+)x\d+(?:,\d+)?)?\d+(k?g|g|m?l)
```

Capture group 1 optionally matches the quantity like 20 if present, capture group 2 matches the unit.

**Explanation**

- `(?:` Non capture group to make the whole part optional

  - `(\d+)x` Capture **group 1**, match 1+ digits followed by `x`
  - `\d+(?:,\d+)?` Match 1+ digits and an optional decimal part
- `)?` Close group and make it optional
- `\d+` Match 1+ digits
- `(k?g|g|m?l)` Capture **group 2**, match any of the listed alternatives

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/kTYmAu/1)

```js
const regex = /(?:(\d+)x\d+(?:,\d+)?)?\d+(k?g|g|m?l)/g;
[
  "0,5g",
  "500l",
  "1000kg",
  "20,5ml",
  "20x0,50l (1 l = 1,70 €) zzgl. 3,10€ Pfand",
].forEach(s => console.log(Array.from(s.matchAll(regex), m => [m[1] ? m[1] : "", m[2]])));
```

Answer (score 0):

Something like this might do, extracting units, quantities, and doses:

```js
const convert = (input) => {
  const match = /(?:(\d+)x)?\s*([\d\,.]+)([a-z]+)/i .exec (input)
  return match
    ? {
        quantity: Number(match [2].replace(/\,/g, '.')), 
        unit: match [3], 
        ...(match [1] ? {doses: Number(match [1].replace(/,/g, '.'))} : {})
      }
    : {}
}

const inputs = ['500g', '0,5g', '500l', '1000kg', '20,5ml', 
                '20x0,50l (1 l = 1,70 €) zzgl. 3,10€ Pfand']

inputs .forEach (
  input => console .log (`"${input}" --> ${JSON.stringify(convert(input))}`)
)
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper {max-height: 100% !important; top: 0}
```

Note that the number handling is naïve.  It just looks for any combination of digits, commas and periods, which means that it might also accept `'12,345,6.7.8'`.  I'm sure we could fix that up if it was an issue for your data.

Our regex looks like this:

````js
   /(?:(\d+)x)?\s*([\d\,.]+)([a-z]+)/i
//   \_______/ \_/ \______/ \_____/\_/
//       |      |     |        |    +--- Case insensitive, accepts 'KG' as well as 'kg'
//       |      |     |        +-------- Capturing group for units, composed of letters.
//       |      |     +----------------- Capturing group for quantity, composed of
//       |      |                        digits, commas, and periods.
//       |      +----------------------- Optional space after dosage
//       +------------------------------ Optional non-capturing group with 
//                                         - a capturing group of digits
//                                         - the literal character `x1```
````

---

**Note**, an earlier version, which didn't deal with doses and didn't convert quantities and doses to numbers, was simpler:

```js
const convert = (input) => {
  const match = /([\d\,.]+)([a-z]+)(?![a-z0-9])/i .exec (input)
  return match
    ? {qty: match [1], unit: match [2]}
    : {}
}
```

---

And of course, if we simply want the units, we could so something like this:

```js
const convert2 = (input) => /(?:(?:\d+)x)?\s*(?:[\d\,.]+)([a-z]+)/i .exec (input) [1]

const inputs = ['500g', '0,5g', '500l', '1000kg', '20,5ml', 
                '20x0,50l (1 l = 1,70 €) zzgl. 3,10€ Pfand']

inputs .forEach (
  input => console .log (`"${input}" --> ${JSON.stringify(convert2(input))}`)
)
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper {max-height: 100% !important; top: 0}
```